# Debezium Postgres connector error: io.debezium.connector.postgresql.converters.PostgresCloudEventsProvider not a subtype

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, debezium

I'm encountering an issue while starting my Debezium PostgreSQL connector:

```
 ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli:100)
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.debezium.converters.spi.CloudEventsProvider: io.debezium.connector.postgresql.converters.PostgresCloudEventsProvider not a subtype
```

Zookeeper is running smoothly, as well as Kafka. Here's how my `connect-standalone` and `dbz-connector´ are configured:

**connect-standalone.properties**

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets

plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/home/user/kafka_2.13-3.6.1/connectors,
```

**dbz-test-connector.propertiers**

```
name=dbz-test-connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
tasks.max=1
database.hostname=localhost
database.port=5432
database.user=postgres
database.password=postgres
database.dbname =test
database.server.name=DBTestServer
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

However, when attempting to start the connector with the following command:

`bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/dbz-test-connector.properties`

It fails with the error:

`ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.AbstractConnectCli:100) java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.debezium.converters.spi.CloudEventsProvider: io.debezium.connector.postgresql.converters.PostgresCloudEventsProvider not a subtype`

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Tried to connect debezium to my postgres it fails with the error above.